# AWS - Looking for a way to locate stale/unused IAM accounts for cleanup across 100s of AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am looking for a reliable way to run IAM credential reports across 100+ AWS accounts.  I've been able to do some of this using awsume and awscli cycling through accounts when doing, but it's a chore.  Trying to find a more reliable way to do this.  The idea is to regularly obtain a list of accounts unused for 90+ days for user notification and removal.  TIA.

Comment: [Continuously monitor unused IAM roles with AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/continuously-monitor-unused-iam-roles-aws-config/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ive done something similar with a PowerShell script (sorry, cant share) - essentially you need to write some code that does the following (for each account):

- List all users with `GetUser` and retrieve the field `PasswordLastUsed`.
- For each user, call `ListAccessKeys` to retrieve their access keys.
- Finally call `GetAccessKeyLastUsed` on each key to get the field `AccessKeyLastUsed`.

`PasswordLastUsed` and `AccessKeyLastUsed` values indicate the last activity of each user per account.

If the accounts are in an aws organisation, you can also script traversing each account within the org (or just as easily use a text/CSV file etc).

Amazon Docs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccessKeys.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccessKeyLastUsed.html

Exactly how you would write this is kinda specific to you (what OS you use, what programming/scripting languages you know, how are you managing credentials etc).